# Detuning in Rydberg blockade Hamiltonian

Tags: experimental-realization

I am reading the mechanism of the Rydberg blockade as a quantum gate. For a two-atom system with Rabi frequency $\Omega$, detuning $\Delta$ and blockade potential $V$, the system Hamiltonian is given by

$H = \frac{1}{2}(\Omega |01\rangle\langle0r|+\Omega |10\rangle\langle r0|+\Omega |11\rangle{}\langle{1r}|+ \Omega |11\rangle{}\langle{r1}| +\Omega |r1\rangle\langle rr|+\Omega |1r\rangle\langle rr|+ h.c.)-\Delta(|r0\rangle{}\langle{r0}|+|0r\rangle{}\langle{0r}|+|r1\rangle{}\langle{r1}|+|1r\rangle{}\langle{1r}|+2|rr\rangle\langle rr|)+V|rr\rangle{}\langle{rr}|$

If the initial state starts from $|00\rangle$, nothing will change under the Hamiltonian evolution.

If the initial state starts from $|01\rangle$ or $|10\rangle$, The equivalent Hamiltonian will be a two-level system(assume state $|01\rangle$):

$H_1 = \frac{1}{2}(\Omega|01\rangle\langle0r|+h.c.)-\Delta |0r\rangle\langle 0r|$

If the initial state starts from $|11\rangle$ and $V$ is very large, The equivalent Hamiltonian is still a two-level system with:

$H_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\Omega|11\rangle\langle \psi|+h.c.)-\Delta |\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$

Where $|\psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|1r\rangle + |r1\rangle)$. you can find more on page 9 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.06101.pdf.

I am trying to figure out how the detuning terms(with coefficient $\Delta$) go from $H$ to $H_2$. If we expand the detuning term in $H_2$, it will be

$-\frac{1}{2}\Delta(|1r\rangle\langle1r|+|1r\rangle\langle r1|+|r1\rangle\langle1r|+|r1\rangle\langle r1|)
$

However, the term $|1r\rangle\langle r1|$ and $|r1\rangle\langle1r|$ don't appear in $H$ explicitly, as we can only find in $H$:

$-\Delta(|1r\rangle\langle1r|+|r1\rangle\langle r1|)
$

Can we just say $|1r\rangle\langle 1r|+|r1\rangle\langle r1|$ equal to $|1r\rangle\langle r1|+|r1\rangle\langle 1r|$ in this system? Or how should we understand the terms out of nowhere？